# Where should I put this question?

Tags: discussion

It's not a scientific one but it would be interesting to read some answers. Probably meta is a good place, but inside astronomy.stackexchange it would get more reads.

The question would be something along the lines of "What would Galileo think if he were to read Astronomy.StackExchange? What would be the most surprising Q&A for him? What would he understand and what wouldn't he?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting question, but unfortunately it does not belong in *either* the meta or the Q&A of this site. Perhaps you can bring it up as a topic of conversation **in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).** Folks might like the entertainment there, but that type of on-going discussion isn't really going to work well within this Q&A format.

The Stack Exchange engine is designed to compile a work of reference; a collection of well-vetted technical writing about the subject of Astronomy. As such, the engine itself will actually become a *hindrance* to extended conversations and sharing. It just wasn't *designed* for that.

Yours is certainly an intriguing thought experiment, but it is more the subject of a roundtable discussion or debate than anything that can be reasonably answered here.

I would suggest bringing it to chat.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, the chat is not that active however

Comment: Eduardo Serra, hopefully astronomy.stackexchange comes out of beta soon and the chat room will have enough users to become active.